# What is the best drive supported by the MSI GE62 Apache Pro-004?

Tags: ssd, pcie

I did a lot of research, but the more I study about the M.2 slots the more I am getting confused. Can any one tell me which M.2 SSDs the [MSI GE62 Apache Pro-004](http://amzn.com/B0150PJR3K) supports?

The specifications page shows this: NVMe M.2 SSD by PCIe Gen3 X4 up to 2200MB/s

But what about the size? I see that M.2 slots are divided under multiple categories B, M and B&M. They are also of multiple sizes like 2232 to 22110. Are either of these SSDs supported by the GE62 Apache Pro-004:

1. [Eluktro Pro-X Performance 512GB SSD](http://amzn.com/B010800UGK)
2. [Samsung SM951 512GB NVMe SSD](http://amzn.com/B00VK1162O)

If these are not supported, please give me a recommendation of an M.2 of 512GB which has good read and write speeds like those above and which is supported by the MSI GE62 Apache Pro-004.